# Guild is not defined in a get channel function?

Tags: python, discord.py

So here is my code, but when I run the command I get this error:

```py
File "/Users/jbvann05/Documents/ColtsTARBot/bot.py", line 43, in test2
    channel = bot.get_channel(706573119325995109)
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

How would I fix this? There is also more to the code like sending messages but it doesn't want me to use to much code

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role(724348979533316115)
async def test2(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    channel = bot.get_channel(706573119325995109)
    member = server.get_member(449692646315786240)
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name='Leg 1 Pitstop')
    member = server.get_member(643885922240430091)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: What parameters does the bot.get_channel() method require?

Comment: Some more context about the overall problem and what the code does would be helpful also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try and use the `fetch` functions, these are asynchronous functions that will return the desired objects.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role(724348979533316115)
async def test2(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    # Asynchronously fetch the text channel.
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(706573119325995109)
    # Asynchronously fetch a member.
    member = await server.fetch_member(449692646315786240)
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name='Leg 1 Pitstop')
    # Asynchronously fetch a member.
    member = await server.fetch_member(643885922240430091) 
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

The `fetch_member` function: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch%20member#discord.Guild.fetch_member
The `fetch_channel` function: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch%20channel#discord.Client.fetch_channel